# Converting Akka Sources to RxJava2 Flowable?

Tags: java, akka, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm currently using the following code to convert an Akka Source (such as received from reading a file using Akka's FileIO) to a RxJava2 Flowable:

```
private Flowable<Buffer> akkaConversion(Source<ByteString, NotUsed> data,
        Flow<ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed> compType) {
    final Publisher<ByteString> uncompressedData =
         data.via(compType)
             .runWith(Sink.asPublisher(AsPublisher.WITHOUT_FANOUT), this.materializer);
    return Flowable.fromPublisher(uncompressedData)
       .map(bytes -> Buffer.buffer(bytes.toArray()));
}
```

My problem with this (working) solution is, that, at least as far as I currently understand it, the `.runWith()` method call already runs the code, i.e. gathers all the data from the given Source, buffers it and then puts it into a Publisher. Is there any way around having to run it at this point? I would like to just define the conversion at this point without the materializer and only run everything once something subscribes to the Flowable at a later point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use defer (sidenote: I had to do this many times because Akka Sources are one shot):

```
private Flowable<Buffer> akkaConversion(Source<ByteString, NotUsed> data,
        Flow<ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed> compType) {

    return Flowable.defer(() -> data.via(compType)
         .runWith(Sink.asPublisher(AsPublisher.WITHOUT_FANOUT), this.materializer) 
    ).map(bytes -> Buffer.buffer(bytes.toArray()));
}
```